# How to create an appropriate tag that users will reference

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I have been looking at tags lately on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange and I have always wondered what the general process of creating one is. Among that, I would like to know what it takes to create an appropriate tag that users will reference pertaining to the question(s) they ask. Can anyone provide me with some more information in regards to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion you are starting from the wrong point of view. The goals should not be to create a tag. I don't see any reason in doing so. The reason that we use tags, it that is helps classifying question, so that you can quicker find the ones that are interesting for you (by tag favorites), or can easier find something that you need.

Most of the popular tags are there from the start. For obvious reason, they are often used, and therefor needed already on the early question. New tags that emerge now are either very rare, and therefore disappear quickly or otherwise related to new development or versions.

Comment: Thanks for that information!! I will keep that in mind.